# Simple Ruby Classes and Objects program

Tags: ruby, class, object

I am writing a script where I have to create an Orange Tree and every time I run through the specified method the tree's height goes up, tree's age goes up, and number of oranges on the tree also increases. But after a certain time (it's up to me) the tree is supposed to die. So in my program I decided that if the tree is 15 feet or more it should be dead. Now every time I run through the method the height, age, and number of oranges go up and once the height goes past 15 feet I get a message saying "Tree is dead" but the height keeps increasing. I want it to stop once the tree is dead. Also how can I add something different every time the user runs the method to go into the next year? For example right now every year the height goes up by 3, number of oranges goes up by 4 and age goes up by 1 as it should. How do I make the height and number of oranges go up by a random number every year? (not too large) here is my code.

```
class OrangeTree

def initialize
@tree_height = 0
@no_oranges = 0
@tree_age = 0
end

def firstYear

    if @tree_height >= 15 then
        puts "Tree is dead"
    end

    @tree_height = @tree_height + 3
    puts "Your orange tree is " + @tree_height.to_s + " feet tall!"

     @tree_age = @tree_age + 1
     puts "Your orange tree is " + @tree_age.to_s + " year old!"

    @no_oranges = @no_oranges + 4
    puts "Your orange tree has " + @no_oranges.to_s + " oranges!"

end

def pickOrange
    if @no_oranges == 0 then
        puts "You can't pick any oranges yet, you have to wait at least a year!" else

    puts "How many oranges do you want to taste?" + " Remember you only have " + @no_oranges.to_s + " oranges on your tree!"
    pick2 = gets.chomp.to_i
    puts "The oranges taste delicious and very refreshing!" 

    @no_oranges = @no_oranges - pick2

    end
    end

    def isDead
        if @tree_height >= 15 then
            return true else
            return false
        end
    end

        def countOranges
            puts "Current number of oranges: " + @no_oranges.to_s
        end
    end
```

Comment: you can put a `return` call if the tree is dead which will cause the method to end early ... also your `isDead` metod can just be `@tree_height >= 15`, there's no reason to do "if <expression> then true else false"

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify your `firstYear` method in `OrangeTree` class to get the height and number of orange to be incremented as a parametre and return from the method when tree height reached a certain value.

```
class OrangeTree

  def initialize
    @tree_height = 0
    @no_oranges = 0
    @tree_age = 0
  end

  def firstYear(tree_height_increment, fruit_increment)

    if @tree_height >= 15 then
      puts "Tree is dead"
      return
    end

    @tree_height = @tree_height + tree_height_increment
    puts "Your orange tree is " + @tree_height.to_s + " feet tall!"

    @tree_age = @tree_age + 1
    puts "Your orange tree is " + @tree_age.to_s + " year old!"

    @no_oranges = @no_oranges + fruit_increment
    puts "Your orange tree has " + @no_oranges.to_s + " oranges!"
  end

end
```

Now, Everytime you make a call to `firstYear` method, you can specify the value with which you want to increase tree's height and fruit's values.

Comment: The requirements for the program is that the values by which tree's height and fruits increase are predefined for each year. So I can't set those values up as parameters.